Type hints and overloading for type parameter
I have a case where, based upon the type provided as a parameter, I want to return a matching type. I am trying to ingest environment variables from outside of the program, which will always be ingested as strings, but which I want to push into whatever type. The function works perfectly fine, but I want for the type system to also support it.
Below is a simpler example that captures the problem I am trying to address:
from typing import overload, Literal, Union
from os import environ

@overload
def get_var(name: str, mytype: Literal[str]) -> str: ...

@overload
def get_var(name: str, mytype: Literal[int]) -> int: ...

@overload
def get_var(name: str, mytype: Literal[float]) -> float: ...

@overload
def get_var(name: str, mytype: Literal[bool]) -> bool: ...

def get_var(name: str, mytype: type = str) -> Union[str, int,float, bool]:
    val = environ[name]
    if mytype == str:
        return str(val)
    if mytype == int or mytype == float:
        return type(val)
    if mytype == bool:
        return val.lower()[0] == "t"
    raise ValueError(f"Unsupported type: {mytype}")

The function itself works fine. However, there is no such thing as Literal[str] (or a Literal of any of the other types listed).
So this fails because the overloading fails. If I remove all of the overloading, then the return type is str | int | float | bool, which causes all sorts of trouble within my IDE downstream when I want to use any of the variables I get back.
I don't want to find a way around the problem with overloading and Literals by using something like:
@overload
def get_var(name: str, mytype: Literal["str"]) -> str
.
.
.

def get_var(name: str, mytype: str) -> Union[str, int, float, bool]

if I can avoid doing that, because I would like for the type passed to be an actual type, and not just a string that represents the type. This way, I can do things like:
my_type = type(old_param)
new_param = get_var("my_hyperparameter", my_type)

In other words, get_var would be much more user-friendly if my_type could be the actual type (str, int, etc.) instead of a string that simply says "str", "int", etc.

Couldn't that all just be considered a generic function with the second argument Callable[[str], T] and return type T?

The advantage of this is it can then also accept callables that aren't a type, e.g. if you wanted to do some parsing (like your boolean example): https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.12&gist=eaa79d4e46146bc9755c0f76ec92a4d9

Agree with @jonrsharpe about generic implementation feasibility, but if you need to limit types to a subset, just use type[str], type[bool], etc. in overloads. Put bool before int to make it resolve first, also int before float (yes, # type: ignore[overloads-overlap]). This will allow passing subclasses of built-in types, but do you really care? Just replace == with issubclass and go on. However, the generic version (with bool specialcased) should be much more usable.

And you have a typo, in int/float case it should probably read return mytype(val).

Literal refers to Python literals as defined by the grammar; it's not a wrapper around arbitrary names or values.

(I would expect def get_var(name: str, mytype: type[T]) -> T: ... to work, but this fails due to either an issue I fail to grasp or a shortcoming in mypy's type narrowing algorithm.)

Should be Union[str | int | float | bool]

@jonrsharpe, thanks, that makes sense to do the Callable.  I just wasn't thinking about the fact that all types are Callables.  Thanks!

@toyotaSupra , I could have put str | int | float | bool.  I just wrote it quickly and didn't worry about style.  But as long as you mention it, you shouldn't put Union[str | int | float | bool].  That is redundant.
